# AJAX Post to knockout.js databinding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to use an AJAX Post to pull a  list from a web service ... It is not returning any data ... here is my call to the AJAX and the AJAX function: I know it returns data because I have used this in my Postback in code behind. Any suggestions?

```
ko.applyBindings(new theatreSel.TheatreModel());
               Regal.showLocationModal();
               return false;



  // declare viewmodel constructors in standard fashion
    function TheatreModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.theatreData = ko.observableArray();

        $.ajax('/Services/TheatreLocationList.asmx/getTheatres',
                       {
                           data: {},
                           type: 'POST',
                           contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                           dataType: 'json'

                       }).success(function(data){
                           self.theatreData = (data.d);
                           alert("success!");
                       });                            


    }
```

and the web service:

```
   public class TheatreLocationList : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
       // public IEnumerable<dynamic> TheatreList { get; set; }

        [WebMethod]        
        public List<dynamic> getTheatres()
        {
            List<dynamic> TheatreList = new List<dynamic>();
            int radius = Regal.Core.Helpers.ConfigHelper.GetIntValue("SearchRadius", 30);
            IFrdiTheatreRepository frdiTheatreRepo = FrdiTheatreRepository.CreateBusinessObject();
            TheatreCollection theatreCollection = frdiTheatreRepo.GetAllTheatresFromRegalByPostalCode("60613", radius);
            TheatreList = (theatreCollection.ToList<dynamic>());
            return (TheatreList);


        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
.success(function(data){
    self.theatreData(data.d);
    alert("success!");
});
```